# C# PrintDocument PaperSource not applied on some Printers

Tags: c#, printing

I have writen some simple C# Tool that Prints PDFs with the Help of SpirePDF

In the Tool i can select The Printer and its PaperTray

I have 2 Printers here and they are working fine with my code (The correct tray is used)

On an other machine with other Printers, it doesnt work, the correct Printer is choosen, but the PaperTray is alway the same (Manual Feed), no matter which Tray i choose.

```
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[MyPrinterConfiguration.GetPrinterIndex(@"invoice_print")];
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[MyPrinterConfiguration.GetPrinterTrayIndex(@"invoice_print")];
```

MyPrinterConfiguration is an Dictionary that hold the indexes of the Trays and Printer on the System.

Are there any other methods to set the PaperSource for this Document?

My Printers are from Samsung and Brother
the others from HP and Brother (both are not working) so it seem not to be a driver Problem.

Comment: Check the tutorial here: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Print/Print-different-PDF-pages-to-different-printer-trays-in-c.html

Comment: @DheerajMalik: That does not work for the problematic printers

But i have found a solution:
I let the user choose the Settings from a PrintDialog, i take the settings from the Dialog (unchanged). Then it works.
Seem that some printers require additional infos from these settings i cannot programaticly change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:
Setting the PaperSource in self-created PrinterSettings seems not to work for some Printers, but when i make a Printdialog, let the User choose the Settings (PaperSource, PaperType and so on) and take theese settings (unchanged) to apply them on the PrintDocument, then it works for all my testet printers.

I think PrinterSettings from PrintDialog have other or more characteristics than i can set programaticly.

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            gpsMyPrintSettings.SetSettingsForType( "badge", (PrinterSettings) printDialog.PrinterSettings.Clone() );
        }


printDocument.PrinterSettings = gpsMyPrintSettings.GetSettingsForDocumentType( "badge" );
                printDocument.Print();
```